# When a press RUN of a Swift code on vscode it show me this error:

Tags: ios, swift, visual-studio

**And I have downloaded swift from official website and I have checked it path in Environment variables**

---

```
[Running] swift "x:\1. Other\TEST\test.swift" <module-includes>:1:10: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1: #include "AssertionReporting.h" 
 
C:\Library\Developer\Platforms\Windows. platform\Developer\SDKs\Windows.sdk\usr\lib\swift\shims/ AssertionReporting.h:16:10: note: in file included from C:\Library\Developer\Platforms\Windows. platform\Developer\SDKs\Windows.sdk\usr\lib\swift\shims/ AssertionReporting.h:16: #include "SwiftStdint.h" 
 
C:\Library\Developer\Platforms\Windows. platform\Developer\SDKs\Windows.sdk\usr\lib\swift\shims/ SwiftStdint.h:28:10: error: 'stdint.h' file not found #include <stdint.h>

unknown:0: error: could not build C module 'SwiftShims' 
[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.24 seconds
```

---

Comment: Please add the error output to the question itself instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @ZandorSmith I have edit the question

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same issue on Windows 10. I just wanted to compile a simple `hello.swift` by using `Visual Studio Code`. After much research, I realized that this happens because I didn't install the correct Visual Studio Build Tools prior to the Swift installation.

In order to solve the problem you have to:

1. Uninstall Swift from your computer.
2. Download Visual Studio (`Community` on my case) https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
3. Download and install C and C++ support (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=msvc-170). Don't forget to mark `Desktop development with C++` before installing.

[image]

4. After installation is completed. Now download and install Swift for Windows 10 again https://www.swift.org/download/ (current version 5.8.1 `x86_64`).
5. Verify you have swift installed by running `swift --version` (you can use `PowerShell` or `Git Bash`. I don't like to use `cmd`)
6. Create a new folder, move inside it and run `swift package init --type executable` (this will create a basic swift project).
7. Run `swiftc Sources/main.swift` or `swiftc -emit-executable -o main.exe Sources/main.swift` (to generate the executable application `main.exe`).
8. Now just run `./main.exe` from command line and you will see the output `Hello world!`

Answer (score -2):

It's because you are running it on Windows. Try running it on macOS (if possible). I got the same error on Windows, but it compiled perfectly on macOS.